# Wrong Graphic card detected

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 20.04

I Have a GeForce 9200 integrated into my [Acer Aspire X3400](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/ID/content/support-product/2219;-;) desktop PC, but  when I run  'lspci | grep VGA' , I see:

```
 02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation C77 [GeForce 8200] (rev a2)
```

I tried to install the additional driver but purple blinking screen

```
*-display  
graphics card:  
nVidia C77 [GeForce 8200]  
Primary display adapter: #12
```

the problem is I can't use the HDMI port, only the VGA.

edit: I installed geforce 8200 driver using additional driver after reboot black screen

used 'sudo apt-get purge nvidia*' to get it back to work

I am sure that i have 9200 because I have windows 10 on the same machine and it says geforce 9200

I dont have uefi so no secure boot

edit2: i did what k7aay said

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-340 && sudo reboot
```

tried it didnt go well after fresh install of ubuntu i am at the same point ijust want to use hdmi is there no way to configure nouveau or something

Comment: I don't think any proprietary drivers  will install on 20.04. I suggest leaving it alontne with `nouveau`. It shoild work well enough.

Comment: Theoretically the same proprietary driver supports both 9200 and 8200. It is `340`. It makes no difference. How did you install a driver? But these old devices in some cases are poorly supported.

Comment: Is Secure Boot disabled in BIOS. But I think the laptop is too old to have UEFI.